# Cartesian power - via recursion

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, permutation, cartesian-product

The original question is here: [Cartesian power (a special Cartesian product) -- choose elements from array, in repeatable style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977819)

In the old question, there are already answers gave a solution via iteration.

I am wondering is there a **recursive** solution, similar as the solution from following link, which print permutations with recursion: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

Currently I have wrote following program, which is not correct yet, any help?

---

### Code - implementation

**CartesianPowerRecursive.java:**

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Print cartesian power of array elements, by recursion.
 * 
 * @author eric
 * @date Oct 13, 2018 12:28:10 PM
 */
public class CartesianPowerRecursive {
    public static int cartesianPower(int arr[]) {
        int tmpArr[] = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        return cartesianPower(arr, tmpArr, 0, 0);
    }

    private static int cartesianPower(int arr[], int tmpArr[], int n, int m) {
        // FIXME ... not correct yet,

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = n; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = m; j < arr.length; j++) {
                tmpArr[j] = arr[i];
                counter += cartesianPower(arr, tmpArr, n, j + 1);
            }
        }

        if (m == arr.length - 1) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmpArr));
        }

        return counter;
    }
}
```

---

### Code - test case

*(via **TestNG**)*

**CartesianPowerRecursiveTest.java:**

```java
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * CartesianPowerRecursive test.
 * 
 * @author eric
 * @date Oct 26, 2018 11:45:27 PM
 */
public class CartesianPowerRecursiveTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        int arr[] = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
        Assert.assertEquals(CartesianPowerRecursive.cartesianPower(arr), 27);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive approach is very simple. Pseudocode (don't sure how to handle with Java static/non-static etc):

Edit: made `if (m < 0)`

```
public static void cartesianPower(int arr[], int tmpArr[], int n, int m){
    if (m < 0)
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmpArr));
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmpArr[m] = arr[i];
        cartesianPower(arr, tmpArr, n, m - 1);
      }
}
```

[Working](https://ideone.com/KgP0Y0) Python code:

```
def cartesianPower(arr, tmpArr, n, m):
    if (m < 0):
        print(tmpArr)
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            tmpArr[m] = arr[i]
            cartesianPower(arr, tmpArr, n, m - 1)

arr = [0,1,2]
tmpArr = [0,0,0]
cartesianPower(arr, tmpArr, len(arr), len(arr) - 1)
```

[Version with lexicographic ordering](https://ideone.com/rUmY15)

Comment: I copied the method and replaced my original one, but the result is not correct, it only print the original array, and returned with count = 1. Maybe you can provide the code in any language that is executable, thanks.

Comment: The `lexicographic ordering` version is nice, I have translated it into Java version in an answer from the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989556 (`CartesianPower.java` -> `cartesianPowerViaRecursion()` is the impl, with test case `CartesianPowerRecursiveRawTest.java` and `CartesianPowerRecursiveTest.java`). BTW, it seems the 3rd param `n` in `cartesianPower()` of the code is not necessary, since it's just array length, and  could be get from either of the array param itself, the code in my question is a bit misleading.